# Installation Success, BIOS can't find Ubuntu

Tags: boot, system-installation

As the title says.
I've got a new Apollo Lake Celeron mini pc I"m trying to install 18.04 LTS on from a live USB. The installation says it's a success, but when I reboot I get a: "PXE-E61 Media Test Failure, Check Cable".

I've gone into the BIOS, but I can't select my HDD as a boot option.
I tried running boot-repair from my USB, and it errored out.
Here's the pastebin:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/6cFH6wjw9G/

I'm no superuser, and I'm at a loss here.

Comment: PXE is for booting over network. It sounds like your system is trying to boot off your NIC hence for "Check Cable". During POST (Power on Self Test) you should be able to hit a key on your keyboard which allows you to select the media you want to boot from - in this case you should choose the disk you installed Ubuntu.

Comment: It looks like system did not install boot loader, so tries next in order or PXE boot. In Boot-Repair it is trying to reinstall grub, but you do not have an ESP - efi system partition. Did you install in BIOS/MBR boot mode, not UEFI/gpt  and did not include an ESP? If you use default install in UEFI mode, it will create ESP & / (root). May be easier to reinstall. But if drive is gpt, you just need to add an ESP. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu Ubuntu now uses swap file, so swap partition not required.

Comment: @oldfred I installed in UEFI, but I just used the default 'Erase disk and install Ubuntu' option. I'll try manually setting up the partitions myself and adding an ESP.

Comment: How you install, is totally based on how you boot live installer UEFI or BIOS. Then settings in UEFI need to match how you installed.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@oldfred](https://askubuntu.com/users/126395/oldfred)'s response is what got me booting properly! (Had to install grub to the ESP partition, which the default settings wasn't doing).